# Spacing in ExtJs is different in IE & FireFox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, extjs4.1

I've a form of ExtJs.

```
    Ext.define('${pkgName}.v02x001001.SV02X00100104' , {
    extend      : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias       : 'widget.sv02x00100104',
    layout      : 'fit',
    autoShow    : true,
    modal       : true,
    bodyStyle   : {
        background  : 'none'
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items= [{
            xtype               : 'panel',
            bodyPadding         : 5,
            bodyStyle           : {
                background : 'none',
                border     : 0
            },

            items        : [{
                xtype    : 'container',                        
                anchor   : '100%',
                layout   : 'hbox',
                items    : [{
                    xtype      : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Member No',
                    labelAlign : 'top',
                    id         : 'member-sv02x00100104',
                    readOnly   : true
                },{
                    xtype      : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Ex-Member No',
                    labelAlign : 'top',
                    id         : 'exMember-sv02x00100104',
                    margin     : '0 0 0 5',
                    readOnly   : true
                },{
                    xtype      : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Branch',
                    labelAlign : 'top',
                    margin     : '0 0 0 5',
                    readOnly   : true
                }]
            },{
                xtype    : 'container',                        
                anchor   : '100%',
                layout   : 'hbox',
                items    : [{
                    xtype      : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Salutation',
                    id         : 'salutation-sv02x00100104',
                    labelAlign : 'top',
                    readOnly   : true
                },{
                    xtype      : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Full Name',
                    id         : 'fullName-sv02x00100104',
                    labelAlign : 'top',
                    flex       : 1,
                    margin     : '0 0 0 5',
                    readOnly   : true
                },{
                    xtype      : 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel : 'Sur Name',
                    id         : 'nickName-sv02x00100104',
                    labelAlign : 'top',
                    margin     : '0 0 0 5',
                    readOnly   : true
                }]
            }]
        },{
            xtype      : 'sv02x00100101',
            border     : false
        }]

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Its ok in firefox and looks like that(desired)
[image: ok]

But in Internet Explorer it looks horrible

[image: not ok]

Comment: This is not unusual. What version of Internet Explorer? Is it in compatibility mode? And as Cobra_Fast asked — can we see the CSS?

Comment: @rynah: CSS barely would help: 1. it's a lot of css in extjs 2. In exjts positions and dimensions are calculated by js

Comment: Yes Zerkms. @ rynah.... I.E 8.......... It's ExtJS 4.1.1 ..... for cross browser I used this code ....<browser:choice><browser:isMsie><link   rel="stylesheet"        href="${resource(dir:'js/ext/resources/css', file: 'ext-ie.css')}" /></browser:isMsie><browser:otherwise><link   rel="stylesheet"        href="${resource(dir:'js/ext/resources/css', file: 'ext-all.css')}" /></browser:otherwise></browser:choice>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check IE:
go with ie8 to: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text
and in the example usage replace the width and padding with:

```
anchor   : '100%',
layout   : 'hbox',
```

Then go to live preview, and check the result. If it appears well, you probably have a problem with your css in the current site.
If it doesn't appear well, you might be in compatibility mode in IE. There is no reason not to see it well.

The second thing I might try is:
It might be helpful for IE, to add weights.
just add- flex: 1 to each of your fields.
It is a workaround, and might not lead to the exact results that you wanted, but it might help.